# controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I trying to learn Laravel but I have a problem that I don't understand. 
I get an error message when I want to run the controller.

I enter 3 lines of command on CMD

```
php artisan make:controller WelcomeController
php artisan make:controller AboutController
php artisan serve
```

Then, I establish the link between the controller and the route.

```
Route::get('about', 'AboutController@index');
```

And in the file AboutController.php I have

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AboutController extends Controller
{
    public function index()

    {

        return view('about');

    }
}
```

Normally it should work ? I looked a tuto on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QASe8bXMMFA&t=56s

I have as error message => "include(C:\wamp64\www\testprojet\vendor\composer/../../app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Do you have an idea please ?

Comment: can you run `composer-dumpautoload` command and try it again ?

Comment: first check is there a Controller.php in `app\Http\Controllers` ?

Comment: have you installed Laravel correctly? Try `composer install` or `composer update`

Comment: @ Hasan Tıngır, @ Tharaka Dilshan, @Parampal Pooni , my problem is solve thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error indicates that the `Controller.php` that your `AboutController` extends.

Is there a `Controller.php` file in `C:\wamp64\www\testprojet\app\Http\Controllers`?

I suspect there isn't, and if needed you can create it using the current [`Controller.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php) file in the Laravel repository.

I'm unsure why this is the case, but suspect it may be due to a step being missing when setting your project up... What steps did you follow to get Laravel up and running for your project?

Comment: Indeed, I don't have the file Controller.php my procedure. 1/ composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel testprojet then 2/ php artisan make:controller AboutController and 3/ php artisan serve

Answer (score 0):

The error might be due to I have faced the same error because I have moved the **Controller.php** file from **http/controllers** folder to other place by mistake.
you should check that Controller.php file exists in the **app/http/controllers**.